# How to design a dialog with 640*480 which can be used on 800*600 resolution?

Tags: mfc, dialog

I should design a dialog with size 640*480 ,which can be used on 800*600 resolution.

At present my dialog size is 411*292 ,look wise this itself looks good enough ,but actually I was
asked to design dialog with the size I mentioned above.I tried that also but that dialog is too biger
than my earlier dialog of 411*292 size.

while using in 800*600 resolution or my dialog seems to be bigger and not able to see some of my controls

This is size of my dialog,

```
IDD_DIALOG_MYPAGE DIALOGEX 0, 0, 411, 292
```

can anyone please let me know how to design a dialog with 640*480 (which should not be bigger).
And how can I make my application to fit to any resolution so that all the controls on the dialog should be visible.

Comment: 640*480 in 800*600 screen - what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have capture ? your problem is difficult to understand...

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs are scaled in Dialog Units and Dialog Units scale upon the current UI settings and depend upon the System font. So if the user selects a larger UI representation your Dialog will grow too.

Best advise 1 I could give: Size all you controls by youself. Pick a font you like. Set it to the Control, calculate the positions ofthe new controls and use SetWindowPos/MoveWindow.

Only in this case you have full Control.

You may also use a fixed font size in the Dialog resource, but alos this font scales upon the DPI untis selected for the Screen...

So best advise 2 I could give: Scale upon the DPI/UI Settings and Show the dialog n a size that the user wants too, thats what a normal dialog will do...

Answer (score 0):

You're in for a world of pain. If I understand correctly, you're being asked to make a dialog that will always be 640*480 pixels. It seems like whoever is asking hasn't kept up with UI development since 1995. 'Pixels' are meaningless in 2014. First, the units in resource files are in 'DLUs', 'Dialog Length Units'. See e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/17/74811.aspx and support.microsoft.com/kb/125681 for some starters on how to convert one to the other. However, with high DPI displays these methods are insufficient. Now it doesn't just depend on the size of the system font any more, but also on the settings the user has selected for how big to display 'things' on various monitors, whether to differentiate between monitors at all, etc. See for a start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . But beware, because there are updates to these API's - e.g. Win7, Win8 and Win8.1 all have new features in this regards.

All of this of course doesn't help you. It's not terribly hard to make a dialog that will fit on 640x480 and up; just make it as small as possible. But this part: "And how can I make my application to fit to any resolution so that all the controls on the dialog should be visible." is really difficult. Does 'any' mean 'also smaller than 640x480'? And does 'fit' mean that it should look 'native' also on higher resolutions? Should the dialog be resizable? You can either go with the simple and robust approach suggested by xMRi above, or you will have to ask whoever is writing your spec to be more clear about what they want, keeping in mind all the things I outlined above.